Trying to find B movie about evil guy time traveler from insane man
I have vague memories of a movie I liked.  It was probably from the 60s-90s and in color, I think.
I remember the protagonist being a man meeting a woman in a restaurant or bar where they are sitting at the table together. They are trying to uncover an evil plot and they realize some guy in an asylum may know something. One or both talk to him and this leads them to discover a time travel device in past or present with an evil guy in some group.  For some reason I am reminded of Knights Templar or astray Masons. Anyway, the head guy is heading to the relative future to start deadly events and he is somehow stopped, I think. 

Sounds like 12 Monkeys

Could you narrow down the year or decade? A 30 year spread is pretty wide....

@FranciscoV. I think you are right. Time travel, trying to stop deadly events, a guy in an insane asylum possibly knowing something, etc. Its gotta be 12 Monkeys

Can we remove "B Movie" from the title? it hardly suits 12 Monkeys ;)

I think you are looking for 12 Monkeys - although I would not describe it as a B-Movie, as it stars high profile actors like Brad Pitt, Bruce Willis and Madeleine Stowe and was directed by Terry Gilliam of Monty Python fame.
Almost every plot detail you described is in the movie:
The time travel:

James Cole (Willis) is a prisoner living in a subterranean shelter beneath the streets of Philadelphia. Cole is selected for a mission, where he is trained and sent back in time to collect information on the virus in order to help scientists develop a cure.

The mental institution:

Cole arrives in Baltimore in 1990, not 1996 as planned. He is arrested, then hospitalized in a mental institution on the diagnosis of Dr. Kathryn Railly (Stowe). There he encounters Jeffrey Goines (Pitt), a fellow mental patient with fanatical views.

Evil plot: The Twelve Monkeys want to unleash a virus to destroy mankind

A deadly virus wipes out almost all of humanity in 1996
  [...]
  Cole is interviewed by the scientists, who play a distorted voicemail message which discloses the location of the Army of the Twelve Monkeys and asserts their association with the virus.

The future deadly events:

As Cole lies dying in Railly's arms, she makes eye contact with a small boy; the young James Cole witnessing the scene of his own death, which will replay in his dreams for years to come. Peters, aboard the plane with the virus, sits down next to Jones (Florence), one of the scientists from the future.

